# Peewee (Python Sqlite ORM) - NameError: name 'SqliteDatabase' is not defined

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

*OS Linux Mint 18.3 (but same problem also with version 19)

Python3 and Sqlite3 installed*

After a lot of trouble with "pip / pip3", I managed to install **Peewee**.

I tried running the following sample script with `python3 peewee.py` but I get this error:

**SCRIPT (peewee.py)**

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase("people.db")

class Person(Model):
    name = CharField()
    birthday = DateField()

    class Meta:
        database = db # This model uses the "people.db" database.

class Pet(Model):
    owner = ForeignKeyField(Person, backref='pets')
    name = CharField()
    animal_type = CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = db # this model uses the "people.db" database

db.connect()
```

**ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "peewee.py", line 3, in <module>
    from peewee import *
  File "/home/.../peewee.py", line 6, in <module>
    db = SqliteDatabase("people.db")
NameError: name 'SqliteDatabase' is not defined
```

I've already done an extensive research on google / StackOverflow, but I can't solve this problem. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried a different approach to the problem... Turns out the problem isn't related to peewee specifically but to python.

**I named the script file peewee.py.**

So, because of the first line of the script `from peewee import *`, Python imports my own script instead of the real peewee package, hence the error.

**SOLUTION**
**Rename the script file to something else.**

*(Comment: ... So sad... a lot of time wasted for a silly newbie error)*

Source:
[Python AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25705671/4350881)

Comment: similar issue for me too - i called my file 'select.py'

Answer (score -2):

This problem appears in vscode
But it does not appear in pycharm
Replace the total include-me-library with include-each-item alone

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).