# What is the script syntax to "import" a SQLiteDatabaseBrowserPortable app module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the Python3 script syntax to "import" a SQLiteDatabaseBrowserPortable app module?

The instruction in CH15 of Python for Everybody (PY4E) is to download SQLite to create and upadate a database. Instead I have downloaded and installed SQLiteDatabaseBrowserPortable app to my Windows 7 laptop. As this cloud app works fine, I now want to know how to adapt the provided import instructions to create the database using the cloud app instead.

The original PY4E code:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('music.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Tracks')
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE Tracks (title TEXT, plays INTEGER)')
conn.close()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts/Python_for_Everybody/sqlite3.py", line 4, in <module>
    import sqlite3
File "C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts/Python_for_Everybody\sqlite3.py", line 6, in <module>
    conn = sqlite3.connect('music.sqlite')
AttributeError: module 'sqlite3' has no attribute 'connect'
```

Modifications I've tried: I changed the syntax to "import SQLiteDatabaseBrowserPortable"

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts/Python_for_Everybody/sqlite3.py", line 4, in <module>
    import SQLiteDatabaseBrowserPortable
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SQLiteDatabaseBrowserPortable'
    RESTART: C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts/Python_for_Everybody/sqlite3.py 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts/Python_for_Everybody/sqlite3.py", line 4, in <module>
        import SQLiteDatabaseBrowserPortable
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SQLiteDatabaseBrowserPortable'
```

Another step I tried and its error:

```
>>> import SQLiteDatabaseBrowserPortable
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#41>", line 1, in <module>
    import SQLiteDatabaseBrowserPortable
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SQLiteDatabaseBrowserPortable'
```

Comment: Can you show what exactly you downloaded?

Comment: The "module 'sqlite3' has no attribute 'connect'" error is because you named your script `sqlite3.py` and it's confusing Python.  Once you rename it, do you still have problems importing `sqlite3`?

Comment: @mkrieger I downloaded http://sqlitebrowser.org/blog/portableapp-for-3-11-2-release-now-available/

Comment: @jwodder getting the same error even after changing the script name to C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts/Python_for_Everybody/nan3.py". 
    import SQLiteDatabaseBrowserPortable  "AttributeError: module 'SQLiteDatabaseBrowserPortable' has no attribute 'connect"   
  "import SQLite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SQLite3'"

Comment: @MelodyScott: I meant that you should be trying `import sqlite3`, not `import SQLiteDatabaseBrowserPortable`.  I don't believe the thing you downloaded is an importable Python module.

Comment: Thanks @jwodder. I was hoping you wouldn't say that. I'll download SQLite instead. Regards.

Comment: Anyone else available to offer a suggestion? I installed SQLite3. Using the code in the PY4E pdf by Dr. Severance I'm still getting the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SQLite3'" for the following code snypet in CH15. 
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('music.sqlite')

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jwodder your recommendation to rename the source code file fixed the issue. I saw my mistake after seeing the answer in 
[Python AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25705671/python-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-connect).