# Can't Run Sqlite commands in VS code

Tags: python-3.x

Everytime I run sqlite command in VS code, this is what comes:

```
File "c:\Users\Jeffrey Mintah\OneDrive\Desktop\Py learnin\saaaaa.py", line 3, in <module>
    Jeffrey =sqlite3.connect('C:/Users/ Mintah/OneDrive/Desktop/This.db')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'sqlite3' has no attribute 'connect'
PS C:\Users\Jeffrey Mintah\OneDrive\Desktop\My first Databse>
```

I have added it on my path too. It's not working still

Comment: The `sqlite3` module should have a `connect` function.  Do you have your own local file named `sqlite3.py`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25705671/python-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-connect might also help.